# Permission issue on vsdbg while running docker.exe - exec: \"/app/vsdbg\: permission denied

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

My object is to debug the Docker container using `vsdbg`. This container contains an ASP.NET Core API application.

To do this, I created a Docker image using a Docker file, and then ran the container.

And to start remote debugging, I used the below command:

```
docker exec -i  a05a0439540b  "/app/vsdbg"
```

Then I got the below error message:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting
> container process caused "exec: "/app/vsdbg": permission denied": unknown

Please find below the Docker file content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443

#RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile c:\vs_remotetools.exe -Uri

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/2/1225c23d-3599-48c9-a314-f7d631f43241/vs_remotetools.exe;
#RUN &amp;amp;amp; 'c:\rtools_setup_x64.exe' /install /quiet
#RUN  & 'c:\vs_remotetools.exe' /install /quiet

EXPOSE 4024
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unzip \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ./vsdbg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#RUN chmod 700 -R /app/vsdbg

RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la; chmod 777 /app/vsdbg; ls -la'

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["testDockerCore.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "testDockerCore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "testDockerCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "testDockerCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testDockerCore.dll"]
```

But I am still facing the same error.

Using the below command to start the Docker image:

```
docker run -it -p 4200:4024 testdockercore:dev
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue today - the error message is a little confusing. There are no execute permissions on the /vsdbg *directory*; instead of "/app/vsdbg" you're launch.json needs to read:

```
"debuggerPath": "/app/vsdbg/vsdbg",
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue running `chmod 777 -R /root/vsdbg/vsdbg`

For me the `vsdbg` is under the root folder.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? Is it an indirect answer? If it is, can you make it more clear what the answer is? E.g., is the `chmod` action a solution or not? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65402004/edit), not here in comments (as appropriatae). But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.